# Is it possible to not shutdown webdriver between two protractor spec execution?

Tags: selenium, protractor

I would like to run separate protractor specs without closing the browser in between.

Something like:

- Open the browser and go to the URL
- then, run "protractor conf.js --specs=spec1.js"
- then, do some actions on the SUT, typically do some actions on our simulator (so, non protractor actions)
- then, run "protractor conf.js --specs=spec2.js"
- and finally close the browser and shutdown the webdriver.

The goal is to keep the context between the protractor specs execution.

Is it possible?

**Correction and Additional information:**

My need is to keep the browser opened between two separate test suites (in separate files) and not between two tests.
I'm using IE11 alongside selenium standalone server.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything actually in code?

Answer (score 0):

Protractor by default doesnt close the browser between each session unless you specifically ask it do so. The below option in [config file](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L477) controls that.

> /**    * If true, protractor will restart the browser between each
>   test. Default    * value is false.    *    * CAUTION: This will cause
>   your tests to slow down drastically.    */

`restartBrowserBetweenTests?: boolean;`

Looks like your requirement is

1. Execute Spec 1
2. Execute some task outside browser(non-protractor work)
3. Then Execute Spec 2

Normally how I implement this is -  lets say I have a task to validate & confirm email from my outlook , which is a non-protractor task before I run next test case, I just throw an alert at the end of my 1st test case asking the tester to manually verify the email and then accept the alert on the browser and then I will proceed with the second test case

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have updated my question.